# Setting up Raid 1 with multiple partitions

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, external-hard-drive, raid-1, mirroring

I am Setting up two (2) new identical hard drives (14TB each), in a OWC Mercury Elite Pro Dual external case, using RAID 1. Going to be creating 6 partitions. My question is:

Do I partition the first drive then install the other one and the RAID 1 mirroring automatically sets up the second drive?

Or do I install both drives, partition the first one and RAID mirrors the second drive as I create the partitions?

Gigabyte GA-EP45T-USB3P

The connection is eSATA.

Windows 7 x64 SP1 (All up to date)

Also, I am not familiar with RAID software, so I'm guessing the answer may lie in the software.

Seems like a fairly simple question yet I can't find an answer anywhere, not even from OWC. I had to resort to the forums.

Thank you in advance for any advice on this.

Answer (score 2):

From the operating system, the RAID looks like one single disk.

You may use any partitioning tool you like on this one disk.
The firmware (for a hardware RAID) or the operating system
(for a software RAID) will take care of the details.